# How to remove subscript out of bounds error in the code below

Tags: r, text-mining

I was trying to write the code as below but in the classifier function there was error. How do I go about writing this code? Can somebody help?

```
library(RTextTools)
library(e1071)
library(SparseM)
library(naivebayes)
library(readr)
library(tm)
library(RWeka)
library(rJava)
library(corpus) ; library(corpustools) ; library(corpora)
pos_terms = read.csv("Positive terms.csv", header= TRUE)
pos_terms1 = as.matrix(pos_terms)
neg_terms = read.csv("Negative terms.csv", header= TRUE)
neg_terms1 = as.matrix(neg_terms)
test_terms = read_file("C:/Users/muj/Desktop/Test.txt")
test_terms = rbind(
       c('Fertilizer stocks surge'),
       c('Nifty drops below normal'),
       c('Stock market bulls at crucial juncture'),
       c('Markets crash'),
       c('Citi Bank stocks soar')
    )
test_terms1 = as.matrix(test_terms)

terms= rbind(pos_terms, neg_terms, test_terms)
myCorpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(terms)) 
dtm <-DocumentTermMatrix(myCorpus)
dtm = as.matrix(dtm)
classifier = naiveBayes(dtm[1:31,], as.factor(terms[1:31,2]))
```

> Error in dtm[1:37, ] : subscript out of bounds

```
predicted = predict(classifier, mat[27:31,]); predicted
```

> Error in mat[27:31, ] : subscript out of bounds

```
table(terms[27:31,2],predicted)
```

> Error in terms[27:31, 2] : subscript out of bounds

```
recall_accuracy(terms[27:31,2], predicted)
```

> Error in terms[27:31, 2] : subscript out of bounds

Comment: Do you mean to create your pos_terms, neg_terms, and test_terms and then immediately overwrite them with "actions.mentions" on the next lines?

Comment: What do you get when you type `dim(dtm)`?

Comment: @ASOlivieri I actually did wrong coding before. Now when I do this, still the error come, can you give a clue as to how go about it now?

Comment: @GSW dim(dtm) gives output- [1]31 40